# How to get my iPhone app to communicate with my server on schedule or on demand?

Tags: ios5, networking, background

So basically we want to build an iPhone/iPad application which could allow user to read our company documents, however when the phone is lost or stolen, we want to be able to delete the documents stored on the phone. To do so, either server would need to send a push notification message to the mobile device,  or the mobile device should be able to communicate back with server on a timer basis such as every 1 hour.

I am new to iPhone development. Based on my reading over internet, the followings are what I found, please correct me if I am wrong here:

- there is no way to schedule my app to run on a timer basis natively
- I could use APNS push notification to send a notification to device, so user would click on the notification and my app would get launched. At that moment I would be able to communicate with my server to get the delete command, and then my app would delete the documents on the phone
- I could use local push notification to schedule a notification for my app, so user would click on the notification and my app would get launched. At that moment I would be able to communicate with my server to get the delete command, and then my app would delete the documents on the phone. this would be same as APNS push notification.

However on the above case 2 and case 3, there is user interaction required. So what if my phone got lost or stolen and phone has PIN protection. The guy who has my phone could not unlock the phone. In this case, my app would never be able to communicate with server any more, thus it won't be able to delete the documents.

Am my understanding correct here? Any suggestion for this case? It would be really appreciated for your suggestion and insight. Thanks very much.

Comment: Your understanding is quite accurate, as far as I know, there is no way for you to perform the action you are trying to in the circumstance you require

Comment: No way on regluar (not jailbroken) iPhones. But iOS itself allows you to delete all the data (as long as the phone is still online and up and running). Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: It seems like your intent is to be able to wipe the phone when needed. That is absolutely doable and quite easy. See my answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279109/257550

Comment: thanks for the confirmation @DanF.

Comment: @Hermann, thanks, could you elaborate more about "iOS itself allow you to delete all the data"? Do you mean via iCloud or something else?

Comment: another question, in this case, do this mean that even MDM API could not be invoked here to wipe the phone since MDM server would use APNS push notification to wake up the MDM agent to communicate with MDM server, right?

Comment: I meant the search my iPhone funktion (don't know how exactly that is named in English). Answerbot already provided screens of that function. Yes, that works over iCloud. If it is basically that what you want then you don't need to re-invent the wheel. The advantage of that function is that it does not require the user to activate your app.

Answer (score 1):

> when the phone is lost or stolen, we want to be able to delete the documents stored on the phone.

You can wipe the entire phone using the [iCloud remote wipe feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2701). Why not use that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the info @Answerbot. My question would be how to do this programmatically?

Comment: The answer is, you can't. More importantly, you _shouldn't_. Assuming it were even possible, rolling your own device security is a deeply complex undertaking. Unless you have a team of top notch security professionals designing the system, you will surely do it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately we are trying to sell this as a product. So we need some API for this.

Comment: It isn't possible on the iPhone, so selling it will be problematic (read, impossible).